# How calculate the under sum of numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How calculate the under sum of numbers
$$\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{4}+\dfrac{1}{6}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{100}=?$$
 I think on it a lot. But i can not find a easy answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by using a modification of [harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number).
$$\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{4}+\dfrac{1}{6}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{100}=\sum_{i=1}^{50}\frac{1}{2i}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{50}\frac{1}{i}$$
Using [an identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Identities_involving_harmonic_numbers)
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}H_k=(n+1)H_n-n$$
you should be able to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to do by yourself or a calculator if you want the exact answer.

If you want a specified number of digits in your answer, then the faster way would be to use the asymptotic formula for the harmonic sum, for instance, $$\ln n+\gamma+\frac1{2n}-\frac1{2n^2}+\frac1{120n^4}+O\left(\frac1{n^6}\right)$$